# Issue with calling a procedure from within Workbook_SheetChange

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I created a workbook with multiple sheets requiring numerous two-way linked cells in different worksheets within the same workbook. So, if I edit cell B5 in worksheetA, it will automatically update cell J2 in worksheetB with the same value. Conversely, if I update cell J2 in worksheetB, it will automatically update cell B5 in worksheetA.  To accomplish the two-way link, I included the following code in *ThisWorkbook*:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Smith,Joe" Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Parent.Name = "SomeProject" Then
                Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("B4") = Target
            Else
                Sheets("SomeProject").Range("B10") = Target
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
    If Sh.Name = "SomeProject" Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B10")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Parent.Name = "Smith,Joe" Then
                Sheets("SomeProject").Range("B10") = Target
            Else
                Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("B4") = Target
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
    If Sh.Name = "Smith,Joe" Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Parent.Name = "SomeProject" Then
                Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("C4") = Target
            Else
                Sheets("SomeProject").Range("D10") = Target
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
    If Sh.Name = "SomeProject" Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D10")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Parent.Name = "Smith,Joe" Then
                Sheets("SomeProject").Range("D10") = Target
            Else
                Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("C4") = Target
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End IF
    'This continues with for many different people/projects
End Sub
```

This worked without issue until the procedure bumped up against the 64k limit (Found out about that on the forum).  To get around the limitation, I created multiple separate procedures called from a main proc, but the cells no longer update automatically.  After countless errors and visits to a myriad of forums I've ended up with **WorkSheet_Change** in *ThisWorkbook* calling a controlling proc in a module and all of the worksheet and cell references being passed in as variables. It's still no longer updating cells on either worksheet. As it stands right now, I'm getting a Run-time error 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set) when I step through the module code at the ChangeLogic sub.

*ThisWorkbook* code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sh As Object
Public Target As Range
Public ResourceSheet As Object
Public ProjectSheet As Object
Public ResourceCell As String
Public ProjectCell As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

   Run "Main"

End Sub
```

Code in "Main" module:

```
Sub Main()

    Call JoeMain

End Sub

Sub JoeMain()

    Set ResourceSheet = Sheets("Smith,Joe")
    Set ProjectSheet = Sheets("SomeProject")

    Call Joe1
    Call ChangeLogic(Sh, Target, ResourceSheet, ProjectSheet, ResourceCell, ProjectCell)

    Call Joe2
    Call ChangeLogic(Sh, Target, ResourceSheet, ProjectSheet, ResourceCell, ProjectCell)

    'Continues on for all cases involing Joe Smith.  I haven't gotten to iterating through project names as of yet

End Sub

Sub Joe1()

    ResourceCell = "B4"
    ProjectCell = "B10"

End Sub

Sub Joe2()

    ResourceCell = "C4"
    ProjectCell = "D10"

End Sub

Sub ChangeLogic(Sh, Target, ResourceSheet, ProjectSheet, ResourceCell, ProjectCell)
    If Sh.Name = ResourceSheet.Name Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(ResourceCell)) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Parent.Name = ProjectSheet.Name Then
                Sheets(ResourceSheet.Name).Range(ResourceCell) = Target
            Else
                Sheets(ProjectSheet.Name).Range(ProjectCell) = Target
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
    If Sh.Name = ProjectSheet.Name Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(ProjectCell)) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Parent.Name = ResourceSheet.Name Then
            Sheets(ProjectSheet.Name).Range(ProjectCell) = Target
            Else
                Sheets(ResourceSheet.Name).Range(ResourceCell) = Target
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

At this point my newbie colors are showing and I'm in over my head. Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong and how I can get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want it to do, and what's it doing instead?

Comment: Hi Sam. Sorry for not being clear in the post. I am trying to create two-way links between cells in different worksheets within the same workbook. So, if I edit cell B5 in worksheetA, it will automatically update cell J2 in worksheetB with the same value. Conversely, if I update cell J2 in worksheetB, it will automatically update cell B5 in worksheetA.  I'll add this to the post.  Thx

Comment: As for what it's doing... it's not updating on either worksheet once I started calling a proc from within a proc. I've made multiple changes to the code based on varying issues.  As it stands right now, I'm getting a Run-time error 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set) when I step through the module code in the ChangeLogic sub.

Comment: Birds View: `POINT ONE` In `Sub ChangeLogic(Sh, Target, ResourceSheet, ProjectSheet, ResourceCell, ProjectCell)` declare `ResourceSheet As Worksheet` and similarly declare other objects/variables. `POINT TWO` the code is in Main Module. How will it understand what `Target` is or what `Sh` is? I see you have set other objects/variables but what about these 2? `POINT THREE` Also how did you manage to reach the 64k limit? I can see lot of unnecessary `Application.EnableEvents = False/True` I am sure there are other unnecessary bits of code as well.

Comment: `CONTD FROM ABOVE...` You inner 5 line IF/ENDIF can be changed to 2 lines. Your Main IF/Endif can use an ESLEIF. That will make sure you do not need extra ENDIFS. Alternatively you can use SELECT CASE

Comment: Hi Siddharth.  Just tried it... got a compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope.  Assuming that was because I declared them public in ThisWorkbook.  I removed the public declarations and got the same error msg.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Siddharth.  For points 1 and 2. I declared all the variables as public in ThisWorksheet.  I've moved the declarations into ChangeLogic, but now I'm getting Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope. As for point 3, I didn't include all of the project/person/worksheet/cell instances will be used for the sake of brevity.  Thx

Comment: Why do you test the sheet name? Then once you know the sheet name test if it is something elsE? That is why you are wasting so many lines

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem..  But why do you need to do this in code, can you not update the relevant cells by simply linking them with a formula?

Comment: I can't because either cell can be manually updated.  That update would overwrite the formula in the cell.  What I'm trying to accomplish:  In Worksheet1, an update to cell A1 automatically updates cell B3 in Worksheet2.  Conversely, in Worksheet2, an update to cell B3 automatically updates cell A1 in Worksheet1.

Answer (score 1):

I was tired of typing in comments so I might as well type here and make it more clear as to what I am saying.

I am not sure how did you reach the 64k limit. As mentioned in the comments above, you can write your code in a more stuctured/compact manner. Currently you code is of `44` lines excluding the `Sub/End Sub/Comments` The same code can be written in `24` lines

**So that is a straight saving of 20 lines!!!**.

Imagine how much your final code will reduce to when you remove all the unnecessary `Application.EnableEvents`/`IF-ENDIF`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Sh.Name
    Case "Smith,Joe"
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then _
        If Target.Parent.Name = "SomeProject" Then Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("B4") = Target Else _
        Sheets("SomeProject").Range("B10") = Target

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then _
        If Target.Parent.Name = "SomeProject" Then Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("C4") = Target Else _
        Sheets("SomeProject").Range("D10") = Target
    Case "SomeProject"
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B10")) Is Nothing Then _
        If Target.Parent.Name = "Smith,Joe" Then Sheets("SomeProject").Range("B10") = Target Else _
        Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("B4") = Target

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D10")) Is Nothing Then _
        If Target.Parent.Name = "Smith,Joe" Then Sheets("SomeProject").Range("D10") = Target Else _
        Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("C4") = Target

        'This continues with for many different people/projects
    End Select
LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: This is, in essence what I did in my initial code example (although not as efficiently as your example).  The issue is that I have too many cases (8 project worksheet * 20 person worksheets * 12 cells) which is how I bumped up against the 64k limit. Thx

Comment: Refresh the page. If there are 8 worksheets then you cannot have more than 8 cases ;) You need to group them like I did above...

Comment: The parent name of a range is the worksheet, What is the purpose of testing if the Sheet is `SomeProject` ***AFTER*** already getting a true statement that the Case is `Smith,Joe`

Comment: @user2140261: True but I am not getting into that yet. In fact the entire `If Target.Parent.Name = "SomeProject" Then Sheets("Smith,Joe").Range("B4") = Target Else _
        Sheets("SomeProject").Range("B10") = Target` doesn't make sense but that is beside the point. I am demonstrating on how to compact the code so that it doesn't reach 64k limit.

Comment: Hi Siddharth.  I appreciate your time in writing out the example above. I went through and replaced my code with yours and, although I was able to get through more cases than before, I'm still hitting the 64k limit.  The fact is that I simply have too many cases for a single proc.  Any suggestions to the original problem of properly splitting out the cases into a module that is callable from Workbook_SheetChange in ThisWorkbook?  Thx again.

Comment: @Ovalstar: Sure I can suggest you the alternative but before that can you make me understand that how come you have more than 8 cases? Since you have 8 sheets, you cannot have more than 8 cases? Or May I see your workbook? If yes, can you share it in wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: The workbook is for resource management.  Each resource (person) has a worksheet listing every project and a corresponding cell for each month of the year (20 resources * 8 projects * 12 months = 1920 cases).  Conversely, each project has a worksheet that includes each resource with a corresponding cell for each month of the year (Another 1920 cases).

Comment: I think either I am not getting your point or you are not getting my point :) How many sheets are there?

Comment: There are 8 project sheets and 20 resource sheets.  Each resource sheet lists all the projects on the vertical axis and each month of the year on the horizontal axis.  Each project sheet lists each resource on the vertical axis and each month on the horizontal axis.  Each cell in those grids represents a case that needs to be accounted for in the procedure.  There are too many to avoid exceeding the 64k limit.  So I am looking for the proper way to break up the cases in a module and have the Workbook_SheetChange event in ThisWorkbook call them. Is that possible or is there a limitation?